# Add type to object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object called `geo` that I know there's an `id` in it:

```
export const Map: React.FC<IProps> = ({ data }) => (
  <ComposableMap width={500} height={500} projection="orthographic" projectionConfig={{ scale: 220 }} style={mapStyles}>
    <ZoomableGlobe>
      <circle cx={250} cy={250} r={220} fill="transparent" stroke="#CFD8DC" />
      <Geographies geography={geography} disableOptimization>
        {(geos, proj) => geos.map((geo) => (
          <Geography
            key={geo.id}
            geography={geo}
            projection={proj}
            style={{
              default: { outline: 'none', fill: '#fdefe5', stroke: 'white' },
              hover: { outline: 'none' },
              pressed: { outline: 'none' },
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </Geographies>
    </ZoomableGlobe>
  </ComposableMap>
);
```

This object is inserted by `Geographies` that was not created by me. I need to tell Typescript that `geo` has an `id`, because I need to assign a `key` to `Geography`, and I think the most common way would be to use the `id` of the object.

How do I force Typescript to add the `id` type to the `geo` object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the library which you are using written in typescript

Comment: Yes, and I have installed its `@types`

Comment: I'd do `interface Entity { id: number; } and `const g = geo as Entity;`

Comment: @SilviuBurcea perfect, that worked. Wanna convert it to an answer, so I can mark it as verified?

Comment: What does `geos` come from?

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem, too bad we need so much verbosity to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface Entity { 
  id: number; 
}
```

inside your map function:

```
const g = geo as Entity;
```

It's working, but looks verbose. As long as your `geo` object has an `id` property, you'll be fine.

I'd reach out to the guys maintaining the `@types` package for this lib and add proper typing for `geos` array, I'm guessing it's an array of any.